# Does this code follow Python coding standards\style and idioms?

Tags: python, coding-style

I have written this code in log.py.

```
import logging
import os


# make directory
directory = 'logs'
if not os.path.exists(directory):
  os.makedirs(directory)

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('testfile')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


loghandler = logging.FileHandler(directory + '\log.txt')

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# add formatter to loghandler
loghandler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add loghandler to logger
logger.addHandler(loghandler)
```

Now, user can use this in any module like

```
import log
log.logger.warn("gjh")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a whole module for a single global object. If you want to save code, just have a function that creates it:

```
def make_logger():
  logger = logging.getLogger('testfile')
  # initializations...
  # ...
  return logger

logger = make_logger()
logger.warn('ghj')
```

With keyword arguments and default values, you can also easily customize its creation if such a need arises (and it probably will arise as your program gets more complex).

Comment: But, won't it create a new object every time I call make_logger() from different modules? Does it not matter?

Comment: @ruskin: so use an object and pass around a reference to it. I would still not make a module just for the logging object. Some top-level object/module must be creating the logger anyway, so it can "own" it and pass around to other modules needing it

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of problems

1. Apparently you are indenting using two spaces and this [is a crime in Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
2. You are using `'\log.txt'` that works just because a lowercase L has no special meaning as a control character. Better to use the os-specific path construction function instead (see [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html))

Answer (score 1):

regarding the coding style I would recommend to use dedicated tools. There have been some posts before, for example this one: [PyLint, PyChecker or PyFlakes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428872/pylint-pychecker-or-pyflakes)

Personally I prefer to use `pylint` with a configuration file adapted to some things that I want to be followed in my projects (e. g. special variable names). If you want to have a quick look, try `pep8`.

Best regards, Rainer