# Is it possible to add static typing in a class?

Tags: python

I am trying to make it so that when i am setting a variable, I get a compile-type error when I misspell it. in all my attempts so far, the variable just gets created.

I don't mind to put the variables in a class, a module, a dictionary or any combination. I just want to have a compile time error on misspeling

here is an example:

```
class Foo:
   bar=""
   def __init__(self,bar_value):
     self.barr=bar_value # want syntax error here
the_foo=Foo("hellow")
```

edit: I had my terminology wrong: I meant **static** typing

Comment: Why would you compile a python script? And how do you know if you're either making a new variable or modifying an existing one?

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. Can you elobarate or rephrase your question?

Comment: Python is Strong type! it's not converting types automatically.... can you give some example for what you want?

Comment: What Kobi said. Did you mean static typing?

Comment: Python has strong but dynamically created types. I have the feeling that you are looking for another language.

Comment: For want you want, you simply need a good IDE, i recommend PyCharm.

Comment: Yes, i guess I meant static typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is strongly typed - the closest you could get using a class is to restrict attribute creation using `__slots__` eg:

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ['bar']
    def __init__(self, bar_value):
        self.barr = bar_value

the_foo = Foo('bar value')
# AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'barr'
```

More info about slots in the [Python Data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

TL;DR: *This class variable can be assigned a string, iterable, or sequence of strings with variable names used by instances. If defined in a new-style class, `__slots__` reserves space for the declared variables and prevents the automatic creation of `__dict__` and `__weakref__` for each instance.*

Comment: I just tried that, but i don't seems to get my error yet. I am using python 2.7. What are those "new style classes" and how do i make one?

Comment: @Yigal did you copy/paste the above exactly? New style classes in 2.x inherit from `object`... hence the `class Foo(object)` instead of `class Foo`...

Comment: yes, i missed that (object), now i get the error message, nice!

Comment: I will. it seems like a very nifty construct. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is static code analysis.  In this case you should look at something like [PyLint](http://www.pylint.org/)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140789/python-builds-ok-even-with-typos-in-the-code) for further discussion.

Note:  Python is strongly typed already, causing the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Note that Python is stroingly typed see this question for [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328920/is-python-strongly-typed). What you are after is  part of static code analysis.

Some IDEs do check that variable names have been set see [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) under Eclipse and PyCharm, and using an IDE is I expect the only waty to get these errors spotted whilst typing.

Code analysers like [PyLint](http://www.pylint.org/) can be run on the code and these spot some errors.