# Should I use Pylint or Prospector for linting error checks?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

I have a python app with several custom modules. I found there are two tools available for linting:
- pylint
- prospector

My question is, 
1. which tool should I use? 
2. Which is the standard way for python linting?
3. Where to get .pylintrc file?

Note: I have to use Jenkins as build system. So that, i can get error reports for linting as well.

Comment: This is not a valid StackOverflow question as the answer would be based mainly on preferences and not on facts.  See this similar question which was closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428872/pylint-pychecker-or-pyflakes .